# MySQL where clause equals anything (SELECT * WHERE col = ANY_VALUE)

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to create a query in MySQL that has an optional value. When the value is specified the query is filtered by that value, when the value is not all rows are returned. Here's the idea:

```
public function doQuery($item = 'ANY_VALUE') {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE item = ?";
  db->fetchAll($query,array($item))
  ...
}

doQuery(); // Returns everything
doQuery($item='item1'); // Returns only rows where item = 'item1'
```

Is there an easy way to do this without creating two query strings depending on the value of $item?

Comment: It could have formulated using PHP as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As far as I know, no such "any" placeholder exists.

If you can use LIKE, you could do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE item LIKE '%'
```

if you can append a condition, you could nullify the `item` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE item = ? OR 1=1
```

(won't work in your example though, because you are passing "item" as a parameter)

That's all the options I can see - it's probably easiest to work with two queries, removing the `WHERE` clause altogether in the second one.

This would probably work, but I*m not sure whether it's a good idea from a database point of view.

```
public function doQuery($item = 'ANY_VALUE') {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE item = ? OR 1 = ?";
  db->fetchAll($query,array($item, ($item == 'ANY_VALUE' ? 1 : 0))
  ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting ideas. The LIKE clause idea could work, but I think it will hurt performance. Appending another where clause would require string manipulation of the query which I wanted to avoid. If I wanted to go down that route, then I could just add the 'item = ?' clause directly to the query string...

Comment: Extending second example:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE item = ? OR 1=?

Put 0 in the second parameter if you want specific rows, or 1 if you want all

Comment: I *think* that MySQL will short circuit a `LIKE '%'` statement into `1 = 1`...  Try it (and I doubt it'll hurt performance much even if it's not a short circuit, since you'd need a full table scan anyway)...

Comment: @Mchl that was what I had in my last revision (Now restored). I was worried about performance, but on second thought, the query optimizer will probably take care of it.

Comment: Im pretty sure optimiser will deal with it great. AFAIR `x OR 1` is always optimised to `1` and `x OR 0` is optimised to `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Better way to do this is first generate sql query from the parameter you need to bother on, and then execute.

```
function doQuery($params) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable ';
    if (is_array($params) // or whatever your condition ) { 
        $query .= 'WHERE item = ' . $params[0];
    }
    $query .= ' ;';

    // execute generated query
    execute($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get distinct results without giving distinct query strings.

Using `$q = "... WHERE item = '$item'"` you DO create distinct query strings depending on the value of $item, so it is not that different from using
`$q = "..." . ($item=='ANY_VALUE' ? something : s_th_else);`.

That said I see two or three options:

- use `function doQuery($item = "%") { $query = "SELECT ... WHERE item LIKE '$item'"; ...}`

  But then callers to that function must know that they must escape a '%' or '_' character properly if they want to search for an item having this character literally (e.g. for item = "5% alcoholic solution", giving this as argument would also find "50-50 sunflower and olive oil non alcoholic solution".
- use `function doQuery($item = NULL) { $query = "SELECT ..."; if ($item !== NULL) $query .= " WHERE item = '$item' "; ...}` (where I use NULL to allow any other string or numerical value as a valid "non-empty" argument; in case you also want to allow to search for NULL (without quotes) you must choose another "impossible" default value, e.g., `[]`, and you must anyway use a distinct query without the single quotes which however are very important in the general case), or even:
- use `function doQuery($item = NULL) { if($item === NULL) $query = "SELECT ..."; else $query = "SELECT ... WHERE item = '$item' "; ...}`, which is more to type but probably faster since it will avoid an additional string manipulation (concatenation of the first and second part).

I think the 2nd & 3rd options are better than the first one. You should explain why you want to avoid these better solutions.

PS: always take care of not forgetting the quotes in the SQL, and even to properly escape any special characters (quotes, ...) in arguments which can depend on user input, as to avoid [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You may be keen on finding shortest possible solutions (as I am), but neglecting such aspects is a no-no: it's not a valid solution, so it's *not* the shortest solution!