# How to define "global" find conditions for model in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to define find conditions that are always effective in all controllers and functions that use specific model?

For example if I want to return only products that are in stock no matter what. Maybe somewhere in model:

```
conditions => array('inStock >' => 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try to do a function on the model, and then call it in controller with a simple line.

**Controller:**

```
$productsInStock = $this->Product->getProductsInStock();
```

**Model:**

```
function getProductsInStock() {  
            $produtcsInStock = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('inStock >' => 0)));
            return $productsInStock;          
}
```

Or try this Link, I think it will help. I just don't know nothing about callbacks: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1049/beforeFind

Comment: Yes you are right. This is how it shoud be done in the first place.

Comment: This might be preferable in situations when you need to be able to disable the global conditions from time to time. With `beforeFind()` you'd have to plase an `isset()` applying the global condition only if no manual is present, but it can get tricky if the manual condition is something like `array('User.is_banned LIKE'=>'%')`. [Here's why I'm using the `'%'` thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3430749/722036)

Answer (score 2):

you can add that logic by overriding beforeFind() in the specific model: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1049/beforeFind

remember to call parent::beforeFind(); at the beginning.

Comment: I'm pretty close to go with this approach, but considering my limited programming skills and added complexity I have to go with the "best practice". :)

Comment: yeah, I misread your question that you wanted to enforce a condition to all find() operations in a model. That's why I suggested beforeFind

Comment: You read it just right. It just wasn't that easy solution I was expecting. (like var $order in model)

Comment: hm.. then what Rafael suggested isn't ideal. Because it's just one pre-defined find('all'). And you can't enforce the condition if you use find('list') somewhere else, for example.

Comment: You are right at that one but I think if you have to use this kind of "hack" there is something wrong with MVC design. Now I have find-functions all over different controllers when I should have few functions in model that take care of the data.

Comment: beforeFind is not a hack, it is designed for that. I don't understand your second sentence: beforeFind is a model's method, not a controller's. And using beforeFind is actually very easy, I can write the solution for you in 3-4 lines of code.

Comment: **There's a problem with `beforeFind()` though**. What if you need to show those records you normalli filter out? Say, on the *Archived* page? You'd have to set up an `isset()` condition in your beforeFind checking if that filter is not applied first, and you'll have to make it complex to catch the `LIKE` conditions you might need to pass.