# Defining global conditions in Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

Is it possible to define global conditions for Model ?

I have 2 Models: `User` and `Student`. In database both of them are using table `users` but each student has set `parent_id` to its owner (which is set in the same table)  while each user has `parent_id` set to `Null`.

When I use for example

```
$this->find('all');
```

in `Student` Model I want to force Cake to return only those records from database table `users` where `parent_id != Null` .

So the question is - can I define somehow global conditions in the Model? Something like that:

`public $conditions = array('Student.parent_id !=' => Null);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define "global" find conditions for model in CakePHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772737/how-to-define-global-find-conditions-for-model-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use beforeFind

You can use [before find](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforefind) to modify all queries issued for a model:

```
function beforeFind(array $queryData) {
    $queryData['conditions'][]['NOT'][$this->alias . '.parent_id'] = null;
    return $queryData;
}
```

Be careful using this technique to not overwrite existing conditions (note the extra `[]`) otherwise a query for "not parent_id 2" becomes "not parent_id null".

Comment: There might be a problem in situations when you need to be able to disable the global conditions from time to time. With `beforeFind()` you'd have to plase an `isset()` applying the global condition only if no manual is present, but it can get tricky if the manual condition is something like `array('User.is_banned LIKE'=>'%')`. [Here's why I'm using the `'%'` thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3430749/722036)

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica very true, which is why it's better to use a behavior rather than embed code directly in a model. Don't know what you mean about `array('User.is_banned LIKE'=>'%')` you should never need to create a condition like that.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the afterFind callback to alter your finds in the model

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['parent_id'] == NULL) { //no parent_id set then remove that part of the results
           unset($results[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html

Comment: afterFind is a useful callback, but it's not appropriate for the example in the question. Consider having many users, only a few students and a query with a limit - it's quite possible to return only not-students, unset all results and therefore return 0 results - even though there _are_ results in the db

Comment: true, your answer is better