# Condition in every query, CakePHP 2.5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I would like to ask, if there is way to (let's say in model class) set where condition that has to be in every single query.

Example:
Model A has field awesome. I want when using $this->A->find('all') to have sql query with WHERE awesome=1 , but I want this condition to every find without specifying it every time.

As far as I searched it's possible when specifying associations between two models

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining global conditions in Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543774/defining-global-conditions-in-model)

Comment: You can look into ideas discussed here: [cakephp-and-namedscope-for-dry-conditions](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/02/15/cakephp-and-namedscope-for-dry-conditions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`beforeFind`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforefind) callback in `AppModel.php`.
You can modify $query params...

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to [create a custom Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#creating-behaviors).

Then, every model that you'd like to add that condition to should utilize that behavior (via the `$actsAs` variable.

In the behavior, you can add a `beforeFind()` method.  In that method, you can add anything you want to the 'conditions' array.

Therefore, every `find()` you run on the models will run that `beforeFind()`, and get the conditions added to it before running the actual find.

Answer (score -1):

To use conditions in cakePHP

```
$client = $this->Client->find('all', array('conditions' =>array('LastName like' => "%something%")));
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is not Answer I am looking for. This is conditions per one find, I want them global.