# Is there a special character in mySql that would return always true in WHERE clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a character, say, $,

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE firstName='Peter' AND areaCode=$;
```

such that the statement would return the same as

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE firstName='Peter'
```

i.e. `areaCode=$` would always return always true and, thus, effectively “turns of” the criteria areaCode=...

I’m writing a VBA code in Excel that fetches some rows based on a number of criteria. The criteria can either be enabled or disabled. A character like $ would make the disabling so much easier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430721/mysql-where-clause-equals-anything-select-where-col-any-value

this may answer your question as well

Answer (score 2):

instead of disabling it, pass it through to your query as `NULL` and use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Persons 
WHERE firstName='Peter' 
AND areaCode = COALESCE(<your parameter>, areaCode);
```

Comment: ...Assuming `areaCode` is not nullable.

Comment: I think that using COALESCE like this will prevent efficient usage of indexes for the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
%
```

See [Wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

Comment: The %, i.e. the wildcard, solved my problem. Many thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use NULL for this purpose:

```
 AND (areaCode = ? OR ? IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE firstName=firstName
```

of course without quotes

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume that you actually want the ability to *include* or *exclude* the `where` clause, in which case you need to use `or`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Persons 
 WHERE ( 1 = 2
         OR ( firstName = 'Peter' 
              AND < more conditions if needed >
                  )
        )
```

In this example `1 <> 2` so the only condition evaluated is `firstName = 'Peter'`. If you then want to ignore the `where` clause you change 2 to 1. As `1 = 1` this is evaluated for every row and the rest of the conditions will be ignored.